# Find out the name of a folder in a root directory inside .zip file

Tags: linux, fedora, zip

I'm using Fedora 17 and bash as my shell. I have a specific zip file, which has just one folder in it's root. I.e. upon unpacking the zip file i see the following:

`> unzip myzip.zip
> ls
myzip.zip folderThatWasInsideZip`

Supposing you know, that there is only 1 folder packed in the zip file, how do I find out **the name of the main folder inside the zip file**, without actually unpacking the zip file?

I'm looking for a one-liner, that would enable me to do something like this:

`> <command> myzip.zip 
folderThatWasInsideZip`

I know there are ways to list all the files in the zip with `less`, but that lists all the files in the subdirectories etc. I just want to know the name of the one folder. I know I'm missing something basic..

Comment: the -l option is used to list the files rather than unpack the zip file. see man unzip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command seems to do what you want:

```
unzip -qql myzip.zip | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5-
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
unzip -qql myzip.zip | sed -r '1 {s/([ ]+[^ ]+){3}\s+//;q}'
```

Comment: That would give me the answer, but it unpacks the zip file. I need to do it without unpacking the zip as I'm writing in the question.. Is there a way?

Comment: @JanHrcek: looking at gdb traces for `unzip` and `unzip -l` shows that `inflate_block()` function is not called with `-l`, i.e. the file is not decompressed, only meta data is read.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

`unzip -Z` invokes [Zipinfo mode](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html), which means you could call `unzip -Z -1 myzip.zip | head -1` for the same result, but it's a lot more terse

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following shell command:

```
unzip -qql myzip.zip | head -n1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

It is a unix command pipeline. `unzip -qql` lists the files in the zip file. `head -n1` cuts its first line, while `awk '{print $4}'` prints its fourth word.

Note, it doesn't work correctly it the first entry in the zip file contains a space. Typically, it is a bad practice to process the output of such commands, but it might be okay for a quick & dirty solution.